# Deploying CXF SOAP Web Services to Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, soap, cxf

I've recently re-written a web services application to use CXF instead of Axis.  The switch was easy enough, but I'm having issues deploying the webapp.  Previously, with Axis, you could navigate to a page, served by Tomcat, that would list all Axis services; something similar to `http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/listServices`.  And to view a service's WSDL, I'd navigate to `http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/Service?wsdl`.

After rewriting the services in CXF, I've found I don't really know how to deploy and configure the application.  I've followed a basic CXF setup, where my application's `web.xml` file imports a Spring config file, `beans.xml`.  I can war all this up just fine and deploy it in Tomcat, where it explodes just fine and no error logging occurs, but I cannot figure out how to even browse on the host to see a listing of the deployed web services.

Can I get some help and explanation for this?  I'd like to understand how to configure CXF so that I know what URLs to use in order to list services and see their corresponding WSDLs.  Feel free to explain this portion as if I were five years old; I'm a solid programmer, but deployment and configuration aren't my strongest areas of knowledge.

One thing I've noticed in trying to understand this is that the beans.xml file references an import of `classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml`.  I have no idea what this file is or where it is, but my assumption would be that it's probably needed and that I should probably understand its role.  Would someone mind explaining that as well?  Does Tomcat's `web.xml` have anything to do with this configuration?

If I can provide any more information or configuration in order to assist with this post, let me know!

Here's my application's web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/beans.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <display-name>CXF Servlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>inc</extension>
        <mime-type>text/plain</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And here's my beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />

    <jaxws:endpoint
        id="accountService"
        implementor="com.company.ws.data.services.AccountService"
        address="/AccountService" />

    <jaxws:endpoint
        id="loggingService"
        implementor="com.company.ws.data.services.LoggingService"
        address="/LoggingService" />

    <jaxws:endpoint
        id="searchService"
        implementor="com.company.ws.data.services.SearchService"
        address="/SearchService" />

    <jaxws:endpoint
        id="validationService"
        implementor="com.company.ws.data.services.ValidationService"
        address="/ValidationService" />
</beans>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access all the deployed webservices in `http://localhost:8080/{YourwebApp}/services` Say suppose your webapplication is webapp1 then `http://localhost:8080/webapp1/services`